# Render email text conditionally based on who sent it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Users can accept a project, or an admin user can do it on their behalf. Regardless of the sender, an email is sent. I would like the contents of the email to be different when an admin triggers its' sending.

There's a `current_user` method in `ApplicationController`. When `current_user.admin?` evaluates to `true`, I'd like to do something else.

How can I access `current_user` from either inside the mailer's view template or from the *_mailer.rb itself?

I'm also open to working with controller/action names. For example, `if controller_name == "Admin"`. It'll get us there, but this method is unavailable in the mailer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the `current_user` to the mailer when you are creating a new delivery:

```
YourMailer.conditional_creation_email(current_user).deliver_now
```

In **your_mailer.rb**

```
def conditional_creation_email(sender)
  if sender.admin?
    # do...
    mail(to: '@gmail.com', subject: 'New  Order')
  end
end
```

Comment: The code that creates the delivery is inside `app/services/foos/bar.rb`. Running the code returns `undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<CallingClass::MethodName:0x007fc576842248>` Any ideas?